# How do i make draggable move to the correct position onclick dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-events

The app is working fine but am not able to make them to move them to the correct container on click of get solution under submit button.

Please have a look [dragNdrop](http://codepen.io/babuharry/pen/RpaJxb)

```
 function getSolutions(event, ui) {
    $("#submitModal").modal('hide');
    alert("onclick get solution draggable move to correct container dynamically");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what is not working or what you are trying to accomplish. What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: there are total 8 draggables, onclick of submit all the droppable should have atleast two draggables inside them

Comment: You will need to provide a more complete example. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve